# Visual Studio 2008 crashes on third time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

I have this strange problem which I can't seem to fix.

I have made an ASP.Net application in Visual Studio 2008. When ever I try to debug the third time, VS gives that error i.e. send report to Microsoft. Now I had to close VS and start again to debug. Then again I am able to debug two times and then again error after which I have to close VS and start again.

Here's some clarification if you still don't understand.

1. Run F5 to debug application. Web server starts. Browser opens and my site opens in it.
2. Stop debugger
3. Run F5 to debug again and everything goes fine as usual
4. Stop debugger
5. Now if I press F5 the third time, it gives error.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Third time's a charm?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all instances of the browser before debugging again. I've done this to resolve this type of error before (using Firefox). It seemed to be a browser issue.

Comment: Ok I will check this. Although there are no other browser instances opened but there is another user who connects to this machine RDP and his session may have browser window opened, but I am not sure if this should be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now I started visual studio from command prompt as below and it doesn't crash.

> devenv.exe /log